# Regex to discard an entire capture if it's immediately preceded by a specific character

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group, negative-lookbehind

Given the following text:

```
somerandomtext06251/750/somerandomtext/21399/10 79/20 8301
```

how do I extract 06251/750, 79/20, 8301 and ignore 21399/10 ?

The general rules:

- in a random string match every group of at least 2 digits followed by optional / and followed by another at least 2 digits; be greedy about the digits (take as much as possible)
- ignore the complete match if it is immediately preceded by /

I started with the following match pattern:

```
 (?<invnr>\d{2,}/?\d{2,})
```

In general, it works, but it has just one problem: it takes also 21399/10. So, I added a negative lookbehind:

```
 (?<!/)(?<invnr>\d{2,}/?\d{2,})
```

Now it ignores the first digit of 21399/10 (because it is preceded by /), but still it captures all the following characters, that is 1399/10. But I need to skip 21399/10 entirely.

How do I make the lookbehind to make dropping entire match and skipping to the next one instead of skipping just one digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a digit pattern inside the negative lookbehind (by combining it with `/` using a character class, `[/\d]`) to make sure a match can't occur if it immediately follows a digit:

```
(?<![/\d])\d{2,}(?:/\d{2,})?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%2F%5Cd%5D%29%5Cd%7B2%2C%7D%28%3F%3A%2F%5Cd%7B2%2C%7D%29%3F&i=somerandomtext06251%2F750%2Fsomerandomtext%2F21399%2F10%2079%2F20%208301)

**Details**

- `(?<![/\d])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `/` or a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{2,}` - two or more digits
- `(?:/\d{2,})?` - an optional sequence of a `/` and two or more digits.

If you need to make sure you only match ASCII digits, pass the [`RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_ECMAScript) to the regex compiler inside the .NET method, or use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Note your `\d{2,}/?\d{2,}` is a bit off since it won't match 2 or 3 digit sequences, only 4+ digit sequences.

Comment: Thanks, adding `\d` to the negative look-behind was the key. About not matching 2 or 3 digit sequences - it was intentional because I need at least 4 digits either uninterrupted or split in two groups with optional /.

Comment: @JustAMartin Well, your *at least 2 digits followed by optional / and followed by another at least 2 digits* requirement says something different, but suit yourself :) The main idea when you write patterns is that the subsequent unknown-length matching patterns should not be able to match at the same location, and yours `x{2,}/?x{2,}` can.

Comment: In that sentence only / was meant optional but 2 digits on both sides were mandatory, thus making at least 4 mandatory digits. Yeah, a bit confusing, I should have worded it differently :)

Answer (score 1):

Albeit not as robust as [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897801/2191572), you can choose to provide a whitelist of allowed chars to precede the pattern:

```
(?<=^|[ a-z])[0-9]{2,}(?:\/[0-9]{2,})?
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%7c%5b+a-z%5d%29%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%5c%2f%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%29%3f&i=8423%2f67544654somerandomtext06251%2f750%2fsomerandomtext%2f21399%2f10+79%2f20+8301)

Answer (score 1):

A different way around is to match the pattern that starts with a `/` and capture those patterns that do not in a group `()` using an alternation `|`.

```
/[0-9]{2,}(?:/[0-9]{2,})?|(?<invnr>[0-9]+(?:/[0-9]{2,})?)
```

- `/[0-9]{2,}(?:/[0-9]{2,})?` Match the pattern with a leading `/`
- `|` Or
- `(?<invnr>[0-9]+(?:/[0-9]{2,})?)` Capture the pattern in group invnr

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2f%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%2f%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%29%3f%7c%28%3f%3cinvnr%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%2f%5b0-9%5d%7b2%2c%7d%29%3f%29&i=somerandomtext06251%2f750%2fsomerandomtext%2f21399%2f10+79%2f20+8301) (Click on the Table tab to see the group values)